# How to disable a specific windows keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm having a hard time finding an answer for such a simple thing.
I want do disable the <kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut for opening a menu. For some reason it seems like it's not possible.

I **don't** want to disable to <kbd>F10</kbd> completely - like using AutoHotKey.

Is there any windows-built-in method for editing the OS keyboard shortcuts? It seems crazy if there isn't...

Using windows 10.

Comment: You can configure that in autohotkey. Do you want to block F10 with specific softwares?

Comment: I do, with PyCharm

Comment: @Biswapriyo I want to block a native windows action, which is bound to a specific shortcut, so I can use that shortcut in a specific app. I want to keep all other windows shortcuts working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this on Windows. Each application handles it's own keyboard shortcuts. It may be possible that your application can be configured in a way to disable F10, but most programs do not provide that level of customization.

AutoHotkey can be configured to **block a key/shortcut when only a specific application and or window is active**.

Here is a working AHK sample script I just wrote to block F1 exclusively in chrome.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance, force

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe

    F1::
    Return

#If
```

Answer (score 0):

Should explicit shortcut scope, especially who should handle the shortcut.

For general propose - disable global shortkey handle by program A, enable handle by B.

1. Use AHK(autohotkey) - program C, regist this shortkey as global by *physical*.
2. Then use `Send` to **re-send** *simulated* shortcut to *active* window, as if there isn't any *global* shortcut.
   Or use `ControlSend` to **redirect** to *special* window B, as if B handle this shortcut *globally*.

```
$+^F10::Send +^{F10}
$+^F11::ControlSend ,,+^{F11},B
```